# Plot monthly anomaly for multiple years in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dataset, python-xarray

I have an array dataset with monthly precipitation data for multiple years and I want to calculate anomalies for 36 months between 1887 and 1889. How can I perform this correctly?

I have tried creating two new datasets, one for the average conditions (climatology) and the other for 3 years, and performing the following function on them. However, my data output has both dimensions month and date.

Data is assigned variable 'precip' and looks like:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'precipitation' (date: 1920, station_number: 42)>
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
   [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
   [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
   ...,
   [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan, 41.2],
   [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan, 44. ],
   [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan, 30.2]])
Coordinates:
* date            (date) datetime64[ns] 1850-01-01 1850-02-01 ... 2009-12-01
* station_number  (station_number) object '018070' '019036' ... '095003'

#Anomaly calculation

climatology=precip.sel(date=slice('1888','1965')).groupby('date.month').mean(dim='date')
the_years=precip.sel(date=slice('1887','1889'))

percentage_anomaly=((the_years-climatology)/climatology)*100

#convert to dataframe
ppercentage.mean('station_number').to_dataframe()
```

I expect output to be a new dataset with dimensions date and location.
The output is a dataset with dimensions date, location AND month.

For example:

```
date        month  anomaly
1887-01-01  1      10
            2      20
            3      30
            4      40
            5      50
            6      60
            7      70
            8      80
            9      90
            10     100
            11     110
            12     120
```

Comment: The code you show doesn't produce the output that you show. It's close to impossible to say anything about it.

Comment: Have updated the code, thanks